# Documentation for Computer Science

Tags: feature-request

Would be cool to have a stackoverflow-like documentation section that explains algorithms, data structures, operating systems etc.

Comment: a) It is not yet clear that Documentation works for its intended purpose. b) Unlike programming content, CS content tends to pass the test of time. Hence, a textbook that is ten or twenty years old is still (very) helpful. I don't see a gap that CS-Documentation could fill. (Well, if it would replace the many crap-filled sites that are out there, maybe.)

Comment: I think that the idea is awesome. But as Raphael said, there are good resources, which are not really aging. The collaborative effort would mimic this from Wikipedia or would require rewriting existing books. I imagine that new value may come from different presentation, examples, interactive content (like betterexplained project), but these are basic materials. Making it more advance would consume vast resources (human hours), and still reading several of them at once seems superior, because one text cannot simply fit everyone.

Comment: Don't the reference questions address 'basic' elements of this? I don't see the advantages of leaving the QA format for this, other than potential different incentive.